# What is the html tag for collapsing & expanding a tree

Tags: html

I have a html code here. I want to put the link "Google link" as a collapse, expand under label 2.

Please could any help me with html code ?

```
<html>
<title> Sample Page </title>
<body>

    Welcome to Google
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
    <li> <a href = "https://www.google.co.in/"<img Src> "Google link"  </a> </li>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `ul/li` and some javascript...

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You are missing `<head>` tags and `<li>` elements must have a `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<menu>` parent.

Comment: There is not pre-built solution for such a behaviour. Instead, my advice is to learn more about JavaScript and its purposes. You can do so by using some eventListener on button click, and adding a "+" button which will display your list when clicking this button etc...

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for

```
<details>
```

It is a HTML5 tag but it is marked as **experimental**.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

So I agree to Zeratops, you should go with JS.
There are existing javascript "polyfills" for the "details" tag ...

Comment: This was just coming in : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/11/28/complete-polyfill-html5-details-element

Comment: **No longer experimental**

  - Very well-supported in modern browsers

  - [Info](https://caniuse.com/details)

  - **Use it!** :)

Answer (score 0):

Use nested `ul/li` tags, and JavaScript or CSS to handle expand/collapse behaviour. A very basic example in CSS:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul {
    display: block;
}

ul ul {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>
        <label for="b">B (click on me)</label>
        <input id="b" type="checkbox" />
        <ul>
            <li>B1</li>
            <li>
                <label for="b2">B2 (click on me)</label>
                <input id="b2" type="checkbox" />
                <ul>
                    <li>B21</li>
                    <li>B22</li>
                    <li>B23</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>B3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```